# How to replace the "button" with "image" in the Javascript code

Tags: javascript

How can I replace the "button" element with "image", so that, instead of clicking on the "button", I can execute the code by clicking on the "image".

```
<input id="hideObj" accesskey="o" type="button" style="background-color:midnightblue;color:white;font-size:18px;" class="btnHideCSSClass" value="Hide" />
<input id="showObj" accesskey="o" type="button" style="background-color:midnightblue;color:white;font-size:18px;" class="btnShowCSSClass" value="Show" />
```

Comment: Put an `<img>` element inside an `<a>` element - whatever click handler you're using with the buttons (which you should [edit] your question to show) should work fine with anchors too. (Don't use just an `<img>` on its own, because keyboard-only users couldn't "click" that they way they could an `<a>` element.)

Comment: Is the script written using id? Then you can simply replace this btn with <img> and use same id for image.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
<a href="...">
    <img src="..."/>
</a>
```

Comment: I changed the code to the following:<input id="hideObj" accesskey="o" type="img class="btnHideCSSClass3" src="https://communities-qa.connect.te.com/sites/GP/PublishingImages/right%20arrow1.jpg;"/>
<input id="showObj" accesskey="o" type="img class="btnHideCSSClass3" src="https://communities-qa.connect.te.com/sites/GP/PublishingImages/right%20arrow1.jpg;"/> but doesn't work for me

Comment: Try removing the semi colon in the src. In addition, press F12 in the browser, to go Network tab (assuming you are using chrome). Then F5 to reload the page. Check if there is any request 404.